# wget in bash script is only downloading a partial file?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, wget

I have a php script that triggers a remote bash script which in turn triggers let another remote bash script (all machines are talking to each other with ssh key pairs and working fine)...

PHP (server 1) --> BASH (server 2) --> BASH (server 3)

There is a whole bunch of functions in the first bash script which all work perfectly, variables are passed right the way through the process, and then at the end there is a command to run a further script on server 3 :

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "/var/www/getpodcast.sh $1";
```

This also works, as the script is triggered :

getpodcast.sh ($1 contains a filename eg : mymusic.mp3)

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -o /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/audio/$1 http://xxx.xx.xx.xx.xxx/complete/$1
```

This should be downloading a file at this stage but for some reason it only downloads a partial file. The complete filesize should be around 115mb, but every time it's run it it will only download the first 10 or 20k of it? That number varies each time it's run, it's not constant.

I've tried using wget -b in this script to force it to download in the background but nothing downloads if I do that.

Am I using wget the wrong way in this situation? As it's being triggered from a remote bash script is there some extra security or commands that I need to supply to make this work?

Many thanks!

Comment: And you're sure that the 10 or 20k is actually the start of the MP3 file, and not an HTML error page?

Comment: That's a very good point. No I don't, how would I check that? I just assumed that it was the file. If this is the case what could be causing the error page to fire?

Comment: can you able to download the file via web browser?

Comment: You could use "less" to try to display your output file. It will warn you or show you gobbledegook (without corrupting your terminal) if the file is an MP3, or will show you HTML if it's HTML. More info could be grabbed using the "file" command if it's installed on your machine, which will identify the file type by reading the first few bytes of data.

Comment: As for what might cause an error page .. I think you'd need to read the file and the error text contained in it, to find that out!  :-D

Comment: Ok I renamed the downloaded .mp3 file and you are correct, it's not downloading the actual file at all. It seems to be printing a list of what it's doing instead. Check this pastebin - http://pastebin.com/B9Lwy9gU

Comment: Answered in an answer.

Comment: please make sure the download file does not have any authentication issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments, you identified that the output from your `wget` command contained the text that wget *produces*, rather than the content of the file in the URL you specified.

According to the wget man page:

```
   -o logfile
   --output-file=logfile
       Log all messages to logfile.  The messages are normally reported to
       standard error.
```

This isn't what you're looking for, so yes, this is a wget usage error.

Instead, you probably either want to use `curl`, which uses a `-o` option the way you'd expect, or switch to wget's `-O` (capital O) option.  Note that wget by default will name the files it saves the same as in the URL; read the man page to see how `-O`'s behaviour is different from this.

Comment: Tried changing to -O and nothing is downloading now, will try cURL instead

Comment: Could not get wget working at all, but curl works perfectly, thanks bro ;)

Comment: -O is for saving it with a specific file name, what you want is -o. Welcome to the world of computers.

Comment: @markroxor, wget's `-o` option saves logging information that would normally be sent to stderr, and `-O` saves the content from *all URLs* to a single output file. If the goal is to save the file at each URL provided to a single instance of wget, then neither of these should be used. Either let wget pick a local filename itself, or use `curl`, which allows each URL to have its own `-o` option to specify the local filename.